# remember password after jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$("#focusform").submit(function(event) 
{

event.preventDefault();

  var $form = $( this ),

        usname = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),

        uspass = $form.find( 'input[name="pass"]' ).val();
        if($('#chk').is(':checked')) var checked='yes';
        else var checked='no';
          $.post("/login/submit/", { name: usname, pass: uspass, checkbox: checked, template_framed:"yes",submit: "yes" }, function(data)
 {


     if(data=='error'){
       alert("You have made an error");

       return false;

     }
     else{
        if(checked=='yes')window.location='/usercookie/';
        else window.location='/login/success/';
        return true;

     }
  });

 });

 </script>
```

But browser doesn't want to promt whether save password or not. Cant't you help me?

Comment: @NullPointer : It's not a persistence problem. I think he wants the browser to prompt a "remember password ?" dialog box.

Comment: When submiting form without javascript by default browser asks you whether to save password or not. With this script browser doesn't ask, just redirects to another page.

Comment: @Magus sorry i wasnt see teh $.post

Comment: why not change

`if($('#chk').is(':checked')) var checked='yes';
        else var checked='no';`
to be

`var checked = ($('#chk').is(':checked')?'yes':'no');`
that way you can be sure you are using the correct checked.

Answer (score 1):

I would do a pre check and use Ajax to check the is correct, this would then return the error or success message, if success continue to post the form otherwise display the error using Ajax

Answer (score 0):

The browser won't offer to save passwords if your `<form>` doesn't have an `action` URL and doesn't have a submit button. Your password field must also be an `<input type="password" />`.

It doesn't work when you try to assign the submit function with jQuery in that way:

```
$("#focusform").submit( ...
```

However it does work if you add an `onsubmit` attribute to the form:

```
<form id="focusForm" action="page.php" method="post" onsubmit="return mySubmit()">
                                                               ^^ here
```

And then return false in your submit function:

```
function mySubmit()
{
    // do the jquery ajax or whatever you want to do here

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Form has action url method and submit button.

Comment: Is your password input a type `password`?

Comment: In that case I would try using plain Javascript to assign the `onsubmit` and return false, to rule out jQuery being the problem.

Comment: How to post via javascript?

Comment: See my update. It works when passing an `onsubmit` instead of the jQuery way. You can still use jQuery for the ajax and everything else.

Comment: function mySubmit()
{  var $form = $("#focusform"),

        usname = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),

        uspass = $form.find( 'input[name="pass"]' ).val();
        var checked = ($('#chk').is(':checked')?'yes':'no');
    $.post("/login/submit/", { name: usname, pass: uspass, checkbox: checked, template_framed:"yes",submit: "yes" }, function(data)
 {


     if(data=='error'){
       alert("<?=$lang['made_error']?>");

     }
     else{
        if(checked=='yes')window.location='/usercookie/';
        else window.location='/login/success/';
     }
  });
return false;
}

Comment: Or you recommend to use ajax instead $.post?

Comment: What you posted should work, does it? It doesn't matter ajax or post is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="temp" name="temp" src='/engine/blank.html' style="display:none"></iframe>
<form id='focusform' target='temp' method='post' onsubmit="return mySubmit()">
...
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function mySubmit()
{

  var $form = $("#focusform"),

        usname = $form.find( 'input[name="name"]' ).val(),

        uspass = $form.find( 'input[name="pass"]' ).val();
        var checked = ($('#chk').is(':checked')?'yes':'no');
          $.post("/login/submit/", { name: usname, pass: uspass, checkbox: checked, template_framed:"yes",submit: "yes" }, function(data)
 {


     if(data=='error'){
       alert("<?=$lang['made_error']?>");

     }
     else{
        alert("Loged in");
     }
  });


}

 </script>
```

And it works :)